# Why does Angular UI Bootstrap use a provider to handle the logic in the modal and tooltip but not in the other components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've noticed that Angular UI Bootstrap uses a Provider to handle all the logic of the Modal and Tooltip component, but all the other components the logic is set inside a single controller that is shared by the directive and it's sub-directives.

So what is the benefit of using a Provider instead of a controller for only those two components?

Also why do the components accept options as data attributes which are read and parsed in the link function, instead of using the directives scope to accept the options?

Comment: you asked the same thing yesterday, why not do a little searching like :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814980/angularui-why-modal-is-not-implemented-as-a-directive

Comment: @charlietfl I rephrased the question to make it more direct and interesting to answer, and it worked because I received more feedback on this question, and I have been searching and reading about this all over for 2 days trying to understand a little bit more about the subject, and to be honest I did not came across the question you shared, but I thank you for sharing it with me. Cheers!

Comment: might have not been brushed off so much if you had mentioned that you had been searching a lot....over all question just sounds like a `why is the sky blue` question and SO gets tons of garbage questions every day that appear to lack any research efforts

Answer (score 2):

1. **Providers vs. Controllers:**

If you look at lines 349 and 350 of [modal.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js):

```
//merge and clean up options
modalOptions = angular.extend({}, $modalProvider.options, modalOptions);
```

You'll see that the options specified by the modal are merged with the options specified by the user, allowing the latter to override the former.  This is presumably done so that at config time you may set the defaults in the provider and then they're set.  Providers are used to configure your app at the beginning.  I assume the other components don't have app-level-configuration and therefore don't need a provider (and can use `factory` or just a `directive`, etc.).

2. **Using `scope: { /* ... */ }` vs. not doing so in the directive**

If you look at a random file I selected like [buttons.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/buttons.js) you'll see that options are parsed like so on line 22:

```
scope.$eval(attrs.btnRadio))
```

One reason to do that is so that you don't create an isolate scope, in general - creating one can mean you can't have another `new`-ed or isolate scope on the same element - so use them sparingly - and it also means that inner content cannot access scope variables on the outside (useful for `ngTransclude`).  If I only need one value from the outside world and I can stick it on an attribute which is the name of my directive then I almost always just `$observe` or `$eval` or `$interpolate` it instead of creating an isolate scope.

Comment: thank you for your answer, something I would add to point 1 and correct me if I'm wrong, is that with a Provider it let's you inject it into a controller and create the component on the fly, while a directive needs to be inside your view in order to be compiled. And I understand your point about passing options as attributes, but I still don't see the benefit since you can call `$parent` to access the outer scope or you can do a binding `=` in the directives scope to update values in the outer scope. I would like to read more about what you think about this. Cheers!

Comment: @CupOfJoe Arguably I think you could use directives in your controller - just inject `$element` and use jqLite and `$compile` to add a directive.  I've never done that and I think it's probably horrible practice, but should be possible.  I'd read the API about providers, factories, services, run blocks and config blocks and play around with them so that you know which are eager, which are on demand and the order.

Comment: The point isn't to protect the directive from bending over backwards to access the `$parent` - the point is that you can easily have two sets of scopes that don't step on each other's toes and not creating isolate scopes when you can get away with not doing so.